# How to solve this with Nest?

Tags: procedural-programming

**Just get {10} from code below.**

```
jason[x_] := Module[{}, {b = 1}; b = b*Nest[# + 1 &, 1, x]; b]
jason /@ Table[i, {i, 1, 10}]
```

**This  gets it right with Do**

*Results here{1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720, 5040, 40320, 362880, 3628800}*

```
factorial[x_] := Module[{}, temp = 1;
 Do[temp = temp*counter, {counter, 1, x}];
 temp]
Table[factorial[x], {x, 1, 10}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`FoldList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FoldList.html):

```
FoldList[Times, Range[10]]
```

> {1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720, 5040, 40320, 362880, 3628800}

To use `NestList` you can do:

```
Module[{i = 1}, NestList[Times[#, i++] &, 1, 10]]
```

> {1, 1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720, 5040, 40320, 362880, 3628800}

Comment: How about Nest? Try to change the function.

Comment: kglr Thanks. Bro. Your Module works really well. Can you modify my code with minor changes to it?

Comment: @kile, I can't  think of a way to get `Nest` to produce the desired result.

Comment: how about ```Nest``` and ```Table```?